# how to set onClickListener to item in ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I know what's setOnItemClickListener, but It set the listen to whole item. If my item contains a button to which I want to set listener, setOnItemClickListener doesn't help. I tried set listener in getView, but in vain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this post for a nice solution: http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html

(it actually works for any View: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick)

Comment: I’m really confused. here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973917/why-does-the-viewholder-pattren-work) said every item in ArrayAdapter shared only one view instance. so that how can we get different views by getParent?

Comment: I don't think that is correct. Every row will share the *resource* that is being inflated perhaps, but not the *View*. You cannot have one View displayed twice at the same time.

Comment: You solve my new problem. how about the older one: why can we cache the reference to "different" instances?

Comment: I got a exact answer on IRC for the old problem. I will post on that page.