# Android: Gridview going blank while scrolling fast

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

the GridView is going blank in android if i scroll very fastly

please give me a solution for this..

Thanks in advance..

this is my code

```
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(ChangedDashboard.this, stringarray));
```

this is my adapter class which is set on the gridview

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private final String[] menuvalues;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] menuValues) {
    this.context = context;
    this.menuvalues = menuValues;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from mobile.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.changedashboard, null);

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(menuvalues[position]);

    // set image based on selected text
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    String mobile = menuvalues[position];

    if (mobile.equals("1")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new1);
    } else if (mobile.equals("2")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new2);
    } else if (mobile.equals("3")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new3);
    }else if (mobile.equals("4")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new4);
    } else if (mobile.equals("5")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new5);
    }else if (mobile.equals("6")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new6);
    } 

    return gridView;
}

public int getCount() {
    return menuvalues.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

Please give me the solution for this

Updated code

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private final String[] menuvalues;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] menuValues) {
    this.context = context;
    this.menuvalues = menuValues;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from mobile.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.changedashboard, null);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        gridView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    /*TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);*/


    // set image based on selected text
    /*ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);*/

    String mobile = menuvalues[position];

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)gridView.getTag();
    holder.textView.setText(mobile);
    if (mobile.equals("1")) {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new1);
    } else if (mobile.equals("2")) {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new2);
    } else if (mobile.equals("3")) {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new3);
    }else if (mobile.equals("4")) {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new4);
    } else if (mobile.equals("5")) {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new5);
    }

    return gridView;
}

public int getCount() {
    return menuvalues.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
}
```

}

Comment: its better to post code, so that users can give accurate answer

Comment: have you try with android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

Comment: just put above properties to your GridView then see.

Comment: i tried that already... but no use..Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

User `ViewHolder` approach for re-using views. because, every time you scroll, you are finding  views by id, which take some processing and may cause very minor delay causing GridView to blink.

Here are some useful links to get idea of ViewHolder.

1. [why does the ViewHolder pattren work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5987664/593709)
2. [ViewHolder pattern: caching effectively](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/viewholder-pattern-caching-view-efficiently/)
3. [Commonsware:AdapterViews and Adapters](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) see ViewHolder part specifically.

Comment: What is not working? What have you tried, post your updated code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue May be problem with the height of TextView. So, make TextView single line like:

android:singleLine="true"
or, If u want 2 or 3 lines for some of the items, then make all the items have 2 or 3 lines like:

android:minLines="2"

refer: [GridView breaks while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761779/gridview-breaks-while-scrolling)