# Add Floating Action Button to ListFragment with a custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-custom-view, android-listfragment

I used this guide to create a Custom ListView that parses its data from JSON.

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/customizing-android-listview-rows-subclassing/

I want to add a Floating Action Button to the ItemListFragment but don't know how.

Tried to put it under here:

```
public ItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_children, this, true);
    setupChildren();
}
```

But it gets displayed to every Item which i do not want.

Here is the code with the full example:

https://github.com/bignerdranch/android-listview-custom-view/tree/master/ListItemViewDemo/src/com/bignerdranch/android/listitemviewdemo

Any ideas how to do this?

Tried to modify inflate but dosen't work:

```
public static ItemView inflate(ViewGroup parent) {
    ItemView itemView = (ItemView)LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fab_view, parent, false);
    return itemView;
}
```

EDIT:

If i place it under constructor, it works ok. But Because constructor is called multiple times for each view, i have to find a way to call it only once.

```
public ItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_children, this, true);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fab_view, this, true);
    setupChildren();
}
```

Comment: add programmatically FAB to your list activity Java class

Comment: https://github.com/shamanland/floating-action-button   with good docs that should be able to follow for fab...

Comment: Thanks for your info. I had already checked how Floating Action Button is working. I cannot figure out how to place it on my ListiView which uses a custom Adapter.

Comment: wrap the fab.xml inside a 'RelativeLayout' as a sibling of the ListView. IMO the declaration of the fab is independent of whatever list u have. Its a sibling organized within the parents borders so as to 'float' above the list.

Comment: Could you please check the example? I get what to mean but i cannot do it in the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution finally was found. Was much simpler that i thought.
ItemListFragment which extends ListFragment onCreateView method invokes the overridden method.

So replacing:

```
View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

with:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null);
```

worked!

Also had to set **list_vew.xml**:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list" />
    <Button />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Are you recycling inflated views? Or just creating them and leaving them by there?

Comment: As being new to Android, don't know so much to answer you. I think this might answer better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912999/recycling-views-in-custom-array-adapter-how-exactly-is-it-handled

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your XML layout file and it will be displayed in the bottom right hand corner.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
 android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
```

Then in your fragment class you can call it with this code

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //put your code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: This will not work. If you look to ItemView its extends RelativeLayout and inflates the R.layout.item_view. After that it inflates each view as LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_children, this, true);

Comment: Because that's in his ItemView class, @Spira . He is supposed to put it in his ItemListFragment class.

Comment: Can you give an example of this? ItemListFragment class dosen't have a xml layout file.

Comment: Oh my bad, then simply put the xml for the FloatingActionButton in your acitivity layout file and call it in your MainActivity java class. That gives you the endresult you want, right?

Comment: No it dosen't. if you check the example code ListActivity is just using a fragment. My problem is that ItemView is used by ItemAdapter. So maybe somehow how to place to ItemListFragment the xml. But i am not so sure how to do it.  ItemListFragment is calling setListAdapter which is using the ItemAdapter and then the ItemView.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Android:

RX is useful here. You can subscribe to the TabSelected event for the TabLayout in your activity. In the example below, I have three tabs. For the first tab, I do not want to show the floating action button. However, for the other two, I display the floating action button.

```
var tabs = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabLayout);
tabs.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);

Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<TabLayout.TabSelectedEventArgs>, TabLayout.TabSelectedEventArgs>(
            x => tabs.TabSelected += x, x => tabs.TabSelected -= x)
        .Subscribe(s => 
        {
            var tabLayout = s.Sender as TabLayout;
            if (tabLayout.SelectedTabPosition == 0)
              FloatingActionButton.Hide();
            else
              FloatingActionButton.Show();

            viewPager.SetCurrentItem(tabLayout.SelectedTabPosition, true);
        });
```